# When building with React Native, an error occurs related to @ react-native-firebase / messaging

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

We are developing a smartphone app with React-Native.
It worked fine until last week, but suddenly I couldn't even build it from around the day before yesterday, and now I get the following error:

```
/PRJDIR/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingSerializer.m:34:40: expected a type
+ (NSDictionary *)remoteMessageToDict:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {

/PRJDIR/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingSerializer.m:35:58: property 'appData' not found on object of type '__strong id'
  return [self remoteMessageUserInfoToDict:remoteMessage.appData];

/PRJDIR/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingModule.m:295:29: no visible @interface for 'FIRMessaging' declares the selector 'sendMessage:to:withMessageID:timeToLive:'
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] sendMessage:data to:to withMessageID:messageId timeToLive:[ttl intValue]];
                                                      ^
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening PRJ.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

The development environment is as follows.

- iOS14.4(Simulator iPhone12)
- react：16.9.0
- react-native：0.61.5
- @react-native-firebase/messaging：7.4.2
- XCode：12.4 (12D4e)
- node.js：12.3.1

I have tried the following.

- @react-native-firebase/messagingを7.9.2へアップグレード
- キャッシュ削除
- node_modulesとpackage-lock.jsonの削除、npm install
- PodsとPodfile.lockの削除、pod install

I've been worried for about 3 days, but I haven't been able to solve it ...
If you know the solution, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using Git? If so, try looking at the previous, working version and comparing the changes.

Comment: @aheze 
Thank you for your response. It didn't work properly in the previous version, and when I upgraded @ react-native-firebase / messaging to 8.0.1, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

what is @react-native-firebase/app version?

If package `react-native-firebase/messaging` is **7.4.2** version, I think the package `react-native-firebase/app` version be **8.2.0** version. You may try this version.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I upgraded @ react-native-firebase / messaging to 8.0.1 and it worked normally.
By the way, @ react-native-firebase / app has 9.0.0 installed.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This worked for me as well, though I had to run `pod install`